# Database driven PHP navigation

Tags: php, mysql, navigation, mysqli, parent-child

Lets say we have following tables

Table `Pages`:

```
 id | short_name | long_name   | token
  1 |    Mail    | My mail box | mail
  2 | All mails  | All mails   | all
  3 | Inbox      | Inbox only  | inb
  4 | Users      | Users       | users
  5 | All users  | All users   | all
```

and table `navigation`:

```
 id | parent_id  | page_id    
  1 |    0       | 4 
  2 |    0       | 1  
  3 |    1       | 2 
  4 |    1       | 3       
  5 |    4       | 5
```

I was working with only page ids for a long time. It was easy to find details of page with only 1 value - `$_GET['id']`, because ids of pages all are unique.

Now, I want to create human readable (token based) navigation system.

But there is 1 problem. Tokens are not always unique.

For ex. `index.php?page=mail&subpage=all` and `index.php?page=users&subpage=all`

Can't figure out, how to find `short_name` and `long_name` (or other information of page) for these 2 pages (by 2 - `$_GET['page']` and `$_GET['subpage']` or more variables)?

Maybe I'm in wrong way. If you think so, please suggest your idea, and explain. Thx in advance.

Comment: Why can't you make your tokens unique?

You could name them `all_users` and `all_mail`

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar no. I need to show parent name and page name on  adress bar. So when I turn on rewrite engine it will look like. domain.com/mail/all

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this doesn't work out of the box, but does this help?

```
SELECT * FROM Pages
JOIN navigation ON Pages.id=navigation.page_id
WHERE navigation.parent_id=(SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE token={$page})
AND Pages.token={$subpage}
```

Comment: My code is not ready enough to test this query but, is their easier way to get result like domain.com/mail/all or your suggesion is to use unique tokens?

Comment: For your example of `domain.com/mail/all`. This should find the page where the parent has the token of `mail` and the page has the token of `all`. You don't need unique tokens.